# LT3652 Inductor saturation current

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductance

Previous question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283539/lt3652-inductor-selection)

In Linear Instruments LT3652 DC-DC buck battery charger [datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3652fe.pdf) (pag 14) there is a formula to determinate the inductor saturation current in order to select the inductor for your design:

$$I_{SAT} = \left(1+ {\frac{\Delta I_{(MAX)}}{2}}\right) \cdot I_{CHG(MAX)}$$

But anywhere is described what \$\Delta I_{(MAX)}\$is.

\$\Delta I_{L}\$ is the peak-to-peak inductor ripple current.

Comment: Provide a link to the data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka link added.

Comment: Not going to answer, as I'm not sure. Datasheet seems to be inconsistent, both with notation and dimensions. BTW, you've copied that equation down incorrectly, omitted the brackets. I think from the context, and the physics, and the dimensions, that deltaImax is the ratio of deltaI to IL. This would make Isat the maximum current flowing in the inductor Ichgmax inflated by half the proportion of ripple current there is, that is, the maximum current ever flowing, which is what you want.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'll correct the brackets. I'm sorry, it's not very clear: what are DeltaI and IL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From context (and having used a lot of parts from LT), \$\Delta I_{(MAX)}\$ is the peak to peak ripple current in the inductor, so it should really read \$\Delta I_{L{(MAX)}}\$

Normally, this is around 30% of maximum nominal current (maximum charge current in this case), and assuming you have figured out the inductor value for that value, choose an inductor that has a saturation rating of 1.15 \$I_{CHG{(MAX)}}\$; i.e. Peak charge current + peak ripple current.

Note the words on the V•μS rating (reproduced below):

> Inductors must also meet a maximum voltsecond product requirement. If
>   this specification is not in the data sheet of an inductor, consult
>   the vendor to make sure the maximum volt-second product is not being
>   exceeded by your design. The minimum required volt-second product is:

See page 14 for the formula.

If you have an inductor where the datasheet does not specify the V•μS rating, I would try a different manufacturer. [Coilcraft](http://www.coilcraft.com/) usually does a really good job here.

Comment: Great! By the way, should I seriously write to Bourns Inc? I picked an inductor of theirs. Because this value isn't written anywhere. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the answer in response to your comment. Cheers

Comment: I can't find that specification neither in many Coilcraft inductors datasheets. Is it written V*us? And second, I found the most inductors to have a saturation current less than RMS current. And the datasheet specifies the opposite. Thanks

Comment: What currents and inductance do you have?

Comment: I picked an inductance of 10uH, Ichg(max) = 2A, Isat = 2,5A DeltaIL = 0,5A (25% of Ichg(max))